# Why implementation of interface methods only within optional class body of an enum constant causes compilation error?

Tags: java, enums

Why compilation of the code below results in error?

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestEnum.INSTANCE.run();
    }
}

enum TestEnum implements Runnable {
    INSTANCE {
        @Override public void run() {}
    };
}
```

```
$ javac Test.java
Test.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method run()
location: class TestEnum
        TestEnum.INSTANCE.run();
                         ^
```

Comment: I know that class cast to `Runnable` solves problem.

Comment: [It does not give a compile error for me...](http://ideone.com/r1yWNW)

Comment: Try clean building the project. The src is perfect.

Comment: I've found the problem (see my answer). I don't know who downvotes the question and tying to close it, maybe resident agents of Oracle ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the problem of Oracle JDK 1.6 compiler. With OpenJDK and with Oracle JDK 1.7 it works fine.